# Child Component(stateful) not understanding parent components index changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and really looking forward for your help here. I created a prototype of my doubt. I have an array of Objects which is my State in my parent component(**Application**) and i am mapping them to a child component(**List**) and this child component is a stateful component which changes its state only for its visual perspective(that means i don't want to update that state in my parent component, of course this issue is solved if i update that as well in my parent's state). So if i update the state of my child and add a new data to the parents state the component re renders and my child components index is misplaced by child's state.

```
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      checked:false 
    }
  }
  onChange = () => {
    this.setState({checked:!this.state.checked})
  }
  render() {
    const {data} = this.props;
    return(
      <tr>
        <td>{data.name}</td>
        <td>{data.age}</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' onChange={this.onChange} checked={this.state.checked?true:false}/></td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
class AddData extends React.Component {
...
}
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      datas: [
        {name:'user1',age:'26'},{name:'user2',age:'27'}
      ]
    }
  }
  addData = (data) => {
    let newData = [data];
    this.setState((prevState) => ({datas:[...newData,...prevState.datas]}));
  }
  render() {
    const { datas } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Example</h3>
        <table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
          {datas.map((data,index) =>
            <List data={data} key={index}/>
          )}
        </table>
        <AddData addData={this.addData}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So lets say in the above example,

1. I checked the checkbox for user1
2. Then i add a new user and update my state
3. The new user is stacked above current state data
4. My component re-renders and now the checkbox will be checked for the new user.

So is there any way to let my child state to know the parent has changed, please find the working example [here](https://codepen.io/dannykoshy/pen/oqqKBK?editors=0011)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: One important thing to remember is key should ideally not be index. It should be something that you have in your object which uniquely represents your each object in array. Having a different key instead of using index  will give you more control on handling such functionality.

Comment: @G_S Point noted. This was just an example created.

Comment: @DannyKoshy look at `componentDidUpdate(prevState,prevProps)`

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif Dude that's kind of reaching my answer. but cant setState in it on re-render :(

Answer (score 0):

it happens exactly because you are using index for key, react uses keys to remember which component was changed, so in your example if you check very first element its key will be 0 (as its index in array), so now react knows that your element with key 0 was checked, when you re-render new element receives key 0 and react applies changes to this element cause it thinks this was your original element that you checked. use original properties from object and it will work fine, if you don't have such properties try to assign id.. uuid is a great library for it. or you can add new data as last element of the array, opposed to what you are doing now, but its not a recommended solution.

Comment: No man that is not the problem. i have tried giving key as the name which is unique in this case and still the problem is not solved.